# Parsing JSON to XML using net.sf.json (java)

Tags: java, xml, json, pojo, jettison

I'm parsing a generic JSON to a XML using net.sf.json. (I'm **not** using POJO Obj in the conversion)

Json that I'm converting:

```
{
    "root": {
        "accountId": "1000",
        "Items": [
            {
                "cost": 0.1,
                "debit": 0.1
            },
            {
                "cost": 0.2,
                "debit": 0.2
            } 
        ] 
    }
}
```

When dealing with vectors I'm receiving:

```
<root>
    <entry>
        <accountId>1000</accountId>
        <Items>
            <e>
                <cost>0.1</cost>
                <debit>0.1</debit>
            </e>
            <e>
                <cost>0.2</cost>
                <debit>0.2</debit>
            </e>
        </Items>
    </entry>
</root>
```

When the correct for my point of view should be:

```
<root>
    <entry>
        <accountId>1000</accountId>
        <Items>
                <cost>0.1</cost>
                <debit>0.1</debit>
        </Items>
        <Items>
                <cost>0.2</cost>
                <debit>0.2</debit>
        </Items>
    </entry>
</root>
```

Do anyone have used this lib and could help me?

Any tips could help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: FWIW, that structure looks fine to me. `Items` is a list; it has entries (`e`). Although your second structure is valid, it's usually better to have containers around your lists. (If you don't, I'd drop the "s" from the end of the element name, since `Items` will now represent an item [singular].)

Comment: Not well-formed XML: <Id>1</accountId>

Comment: Looks like a bug in the lib. Can you show us the original JSON?

Comment: @Vladmin: accountId is a typo I change some fields to looks more simple here

Comment: If you're still looking for a solution, and don't mind adding another library, the Practical XML converter will do this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/practicalxml -- full disclosure: I'm admin and main contributor to this project

Comment: @kdgregory: Thanks for your answer, I take a quick look in your project, I'll have to spend more time on this issue, maybe I'll ping you latter to talk about it!
Thanks and cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Change the JSON to this format..

{
    "root": {
        "accountId": "1000",
        "Items":{"Item":{"cost": 0.1,"debit": 0.1,"cost": 0.2,"debit": 0.2} }
         }
}